# Statement sequencing in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

i am trying to compile a quite simple haskell program.  Either I don't know how to sequence statements (expressions) in Haskell, or there isn't a way to do it.

I essentially want a function of the form:

```
f = <do stuff 1>
    <do stuff 2>
    ...
```

the following was supposed to simulate a pattern of

```
<do stuff>
<tail recursion>
```

but failed to compile:

```
go 0 = 0
go i =  case i of
            1 -> 2
            _ -> 3
        go (i-1)
```

This doesn't work either (simpler, no recursion):

```
go i =  1
        2
```

The code directly above compiles, but while running I get the cryptic:

```
No instance for (Num (a0 -> t0))
  arising from a use of `go'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (a0 -> t0))
In the expression: go 2
In an equation for `it': it = go 2
```

Am I having a problem with indention?  A problem with not sequencing correctly?  Or is there no sequencing capability?  If no sequencing, how would you straightforwardly do

```
<do stuff>
<tail recursion>
```

?

---

Thanks for the responses.

Hard to believe a function in Haskell is basically limited to one "expression" or "statement" or whatever you want to call it.  How would you solve the following contrived toy example (written in erlang, but could easily be translated direcly into prolog or a whole host of other langs):

```
count([], X) -> X;
count([_|B], X) ->
    Y = X+1,
    count(B, Y).
```

An example run:

```
erlang> count([a,b,c,d,e],0).
5
```

The 2nd clause fits the pattern I described earlier of:

```
<do stuff>
<tail recursion>
```

I guess this particular example maps onto the Haskell  "let... in" someone described here.  But what if there needs to be 10 "do stuffs", or 20, or more?  And is this "let... in" guaranteed to be tail recursive (the above example is guaranteed to be in erlang, prolog, scheme, etc).

Is there a way I can simply "string together" or "sequence" a bunch of statements or expressions?  In prolog or erlang the sequencing is accomplished by the comma (see toy example above).  In c/c++ it is accomplished by the semicolon.  I thought the Haskell operator was simply whitespace, but perhaps it just isn't done in this language?

Comment: What is sequencing of expressions supposed to do? Evaluate the first, discard it, evaluate and result in the second? That does not make sense, evaluating pure code never has any side effects.

Comment: I suggest you study the syntax of Haskell a little before you start writing code.  Statements in Haskell are introduced by `do` and only relevant in monadic code.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `let ... in ...`? (Not sequencing: introducing variables and then using them in a subsequent expression.) Without knowing what your simple program is trying to do, we can't help you with it.

Comment: @delnan: It does make sense in some cases (you just described what `seq` does), but not here.

Comment: @hammar `seq` is useful, although it has no effect (besides sometimes changing time or space efficency). But I seriously doubt we should even tell OP about that. Semantically, it should have no effect (of course it does, as it makes some code work instead of overflow the stack, and I believe it has issues with bottom - but it's convenient to ignore that while it does not matter). Therefore I'd opt to not mention it to beginners at all unless they specifically need it.

Comment: @delnan: `seq` does have the semantic effect that the result is bottom if the first argument is bottom, but I agree that it's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: If the "do stuff" you want to do is introduce new bindings, then a `let` expression will suffice. You can introduce multiple bindings in a single let statement by separating them with newlines, or with semicolons. Additionally, tail recursion is meaningless in the presence of non-strictness; the Haskell stack works much differently than a strict language's stack does. In regards to your final question, I stand by my original answer: in Haskell you *compose*. For IO actions, this is often done with `>>=`. For pure functions, `.` is the canonical composition operator.

Answer (score 25):

[Obligatory meme](http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3ok8cj/)

In Haskell, you don't write functions that "do stuff". You write functions that compute a value. In that light, it makes no sense to structure a function in the way you suggest:

```
f = <do stuff 1>
    <do stuff 2>
```

Instead, you write an actual, math-y *function*, which is a *single* expression dependent on certain inputs:

```
f x y = blah x blah y blah
```

It might be convenient to break it up into sub-expressions

```
f x y = res1 + res2
  where res1 = x * 3
        res2 = y + 4
```

But in the end, it is just a single expression.

---

Monadic code written in `do` notation can appear to "do stuff" sequentially:

```
f = do
  thing1
  thing2
```

But this is just an illusion. It desugars into a single expression as well:

```
f = thing1 >> thing2
```

This expression states that `f` is a value which is the composition of `thing1` and `thing2`. Now, IO code might *compile* to code that "does stuff" sequentially, but that's not what it means in Haskell. One does not simply "do stuff" in Haskell. Instead, you *compose*.

Comment: +1 for a decent explanation that makes clever use of an internet meme.

Comment: your haskell code appears to be sequential, in that res1 and res2 are computed before res1+res2 are computed, no?  so can you accomplish the same thing with your do?

Comment: @XYZ: `res1` and `res2` aren't necessarily computed before the expression.  (They are in this case, but _not_ just because they were defined in the `while` clause.)  Because Haskell is lazy, the compiler is free to reorder those computations however it wants.  You're _not_ specifying an execution order; you're just specifying how to compute `res1` and `res2` whenever they're needed.

Comment: For example, if it was `f x y = if res2 /= 0 then res1 else 0 where ...`, then `res1` wouldn't necessarily get computed _at all_ unless `res2` was nonzero.

Answer (score 5):

It is very good that you were able to provide an Erlang code example of what you mean by 'doing stuff'. Until now it's been a little vague. So long as the discussion is only about strict languages, it's okay to be somewhat vague on that point since the rules are fairly uniform and understood.

On the other hand, we are talking about Haskell, a language with 'lazy' evaluation, so it is good to be very specific about what 'doing stuff' means, otherwise there is likely to be confusion due to incorrect assumptions.

Here's a fairly direct translation of the Erlang function you provided in Haskell:

```
count ([],x) = x
count (_:b, x) =
    let y = x + 1
    in count (b, y)
```

As you can see, it's pretty much identical in structure to the Erlang version. As such, you may be wondering what is the big deal? If it's that easy to 'do stuff' in Haskell, then why is everyone making it sound so complicated?

One way to explain what is the big deal is to point out that the above Haskell function is equivalent to this one:

```
count ([],x) = x
count (_:b, x) = count (b, x + 1)
```

Also this one:

```
count ([],x) = x
count (_:b, x) = count (b, y) where y = x + 1
```

This is because the order in which Haskell evaluates expressions does not depend on the lexical order of those expressions. In general, Haskell will delay expression evaluation to the last possible moment.

Now when you think about composing this scheme of lazy evaluation together with side-effects (reading or writing files, sending output to the screen, etc.), it gets a little fuzzy. The order in which side-effects happen is generally very important. Fortunately, functions in Haskell that deal with side-effects generally do not perform the side-effecting action themselves. Rather they produce an 'action' value that *describes* the side-effect. Then there are other functions that can compose these 'action' values in a way that respects order. Then you just need something that will actually perform the side-effects that are described by the 'action' values...

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there is no way to do it. Haskell is a purely functional language, there is neither change nor order of statements. One way to simulate sequence are *monads*. There are plenty of tutorials in the internet, I personally advise you to read the monad-chapters of [Learn You A Haskell For Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) or [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/). Another thing is: Sequential operations are not very idiomatic in Haskell. You should better start with something different.

Comment: I strongly disagree with "there is no way to do it". I'd say instead "there is a universal way to do it, and you can express uniformly whatever you could ever mean by 'sequencing' with it" (always stay positive !)

Comment: @AlexandreC That's what I wanted to hint by »One way to *simulate* sequence...«. Your wording is probably better, feel free to adjust my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "do stuff", what do you mean?

- calculate something, transform data we already have?
- interact with the user, read/write a file, download something from the web?

In the first case, use `let`...`in`:

```
quadraticRoots a b c = let discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c
                           root = sqrt discriminant
                       in case compare discriminant 0 of
                               LT -> []
                               EQ -> [-b / (2 * a)]
                               GT -> [(-b + root) / (2 * a), (-b - root) / (2 * a)]
```

In the second case, use `do` notation:

```
main = do args <- getArgs
          case map read args of
               [a, b, c] -> putStrLn $ case quadraticRoots a b c of
                                            [] -> "no real roots"
                                            [x] -> "single root: " ++ show x
                                            [x1, x2] -> unwords ["two real roots:", show x1,
                                                                 "and", show x2]
               _ -> hPutStrLn stderr "Please provide three coefficients on the command line"
```

Comment: I suggest `sqrt` instead of `(** 0.5)`, it's faster and more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Be careful that you’re not writing Scheme programs in Haskell. Accumulating parameters are rare in idiomatic Haskell, which uses laziness rather than tail recursion.

For example, the definition of `count` in Haskell will resemble

```
count [] = 0
count (x:xs) = 1 + count xs
```

You might object that the [source of `length`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-List.html#length) looks more Scheme-ish

```
-- | /O(n)/. 'length' returns the length of a finite list as an 'Int'.
-- It is an instance of the more general 'Data.List.genericLength',
-- the result type of which may be any kind of number.
length                  :: [a] -> Int
length l                =  len l 0#
  where
    len :: [a] -> Int# -> Int
    len []     a# = I# a#
    len (_:xs) a# = len xs (a# +# 1#)
```

but this is low-level, non-idiomatic code. The referenced [`genericLength`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#genericLength) has the same structure as `count` above and has broader applicability when compared to `length`.

```
genericLength           :: (Num i) => [b] -> i
genericLength []        =  0
genericLength (_:l)     =  1 + genericLength l
```

“Do this and then do that” in Haskell is expressed as function composition in pure code. For example, to compute the length of the longest sublist, we’d compute the sublists’ lengths and then the maximum over those lengths. In Haskell, that’s expressed

```
Prelude> :t maximum . map length
maximum . map length :: [[a]] -> Int
```

or

```
Prelude> :m + Data.List 
Prelude Data.List> :t maximum . map genericLength
maximum . map genericLength :: (Ord c, Num c) => [[b]] -> c
```

Note: laziness adds nuance, but the general point holds.

Even in “imperative” code inside `IO` such as

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr "Hello "
  purStrLn "world!"
```

is function composition under the covers because it has the same semantics as

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStr "Hello " >>= \_ -> putStrLn "world!"
```

Perhaps an example that uses the list monad will make this clearer. Say we want all Pythagorean triples `(a,b,c)` such that no component is greater than some maximum *n*.

```
import Control.Monad (guard)

triples :: Integer -> [(Integer,Integer,Integer)]
triples n = do
  a <- [1 .. n]
  b <- [a .. n]
  c <- [b .. n]
  guard $ a*a + b*b == c*c
  return (a,b,c)
```

As you can see, we must first choose a candidate value of `a`, then of `b`, and so on.

The compiler transforms this code to explicitly use `>>=`, the monadic bind combinator.

```
-- indented to show nested scopes
triples_bind :: Integer -> [(Integer,Integer,Integer)]
triples_bind n =
  [1 .. n] >>= \a ->
    [a .. n] >>= \b ->
      [b .. n] >>= \c ->
        (guard $ a*a + b*b == c*c) >>= \_ ->
          return (a,b,c)
```

Inside the list monad, `>>=` is [`concatMap`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3aconcatMap), so the above is identical to

```
triples_stacked :: Integer -> [(Integer,Integer,Integer)]
triples_stacked n =
  concatMap (\a ->
    concatMap (\b ->
      concatMap (\c ->
        concatMap (\_ ->
          [(a,b,c)])
          (guard $ a*a + b*b == c*c))
        [b .. n])
      [a .. n])
    [1 .. n]
```

The indentation shows structure and is pleasing because it gives the impression of the Haskell logo that combines λ with `>>=`.

Yet another way to express the same semantics is

```
triples_cm n = concatMap step2 [1 .. n]  -- step 1
  where step2 a = concatMap step3 [a .. n]
          where step3 b = concatMap step4 [b .. n]
                  where step4 c = concatMap step5 (guard $ a*a + b*b == c*c)
                          where step5 _ = [(a,b,c)]
```

---

Haskell’s pattern matching already does `case` matching behind the scenes. Instead of

```
go 0 = 0
go i =  case i of
            1 -> 2
            _ -> 3
        go (i-1)
```

finish the pattern you started.

```
go 0 = 0
go 1 = go (2 - 1)
go _ = go (3 - 1)
```

Remember that variables in Haskell are *immutable*: they do not have destructive update as in C or Java. You get one shot at defining a variable’s value, and then you’re stuck with it. You might instead define `go` as

```
go 0 = 0
go x = let i = case x of 1 -> 2
                         _ -> 3
       in go (i - 1)
```

or

```
go 0 = 0
go x | x == 1    = go (2 - 1)
     | otherwise = go (3 - 1)
```

The examples above all typecheck but have the same big problem, namely that `go` terminates only when its argument is zero. You didn’t provide enough information for us to help with that problem. Tell us what it is you’re trying to do, and we can offer specific advice for your situation.

Comment: yup, already know haskell does pattern matching / case matching behind the scenes, and that the toy example could have been converted to your example.  the point was simply to create an expression that "did stuff", thus the case statement (it could have been any other statement/expression).  see edit at the top of my post for count function which is less of a "toy" example (although still a toy example).  the point isn't to focus on any particulars though, but rather "how do you have several expressions or statements in 1 function (i.e. 'sequencing'), or is it possible?"

Comment: @XYZ See updated answer. Try not to speak Haskell with an imperative accent. Yes, you can express explicit sequencing in `IO`, but that should be the exception. Keep most of your code in the nice, happy purely functional world with the thinnest imperative skin possible for interacting with the outside world.

Comment: didn't know i was speaking "imperative" per se.  do you consider the erlang example i posted to be imperative code?  it has "sequencing" but i figured most people would call it a "functional" style (btw, when I say "sequencing" i don't necessarily mean IO, i just mean "expressions in a sequence"), and it has no destructive updates.  either way, thanks so much for that in-depth explanation!  very insightful!

Comment: @XYZ: Your count example would become `count [] x = x; count (_:bs) x = count bs (1 + x)`  -- or you could write it with `count [] x = x; count (_:bs) x = let y = x + 1 in count bs x` or equivalently `count [] x = x; count (_:bs) x = count bs y where y = x + 1`. you are looking for a let or where clause to make those local names for you, but these aren't ordered effects, let doesn't make things happen, just allows you to reference shared values/computations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure got correctly what your function has to do. May be you need something like this:

```
go :: Int -> Int
go 0 = 0
go i = go (i-1)
```

if that function takes argument e.g. '3' it calculates go 3 -> go 2 -> go 1 -> go 0 -> 0 and get answer '0'

Now if you want some sequencing you can use keyword 'do', but I am sure it is now what you need. If you are trying to create some kind of 'variables' look at 'let' & 'in' statements :

```
someInput = 7

gogogo 0  = 0
gogogo n = 
    let
        gavk = n + 1
        kravk = gavk * 2
        out = kravk + 1
    in 
        out

main = 
   do
       putStrLn "this is sample do statement"
       putStrLn "gogogo:"
       putStrLn $ gogogo someInput
```

UPD. edited mistypes

Comment: What are `imput`, `input`, and `gogogo`?

Comment: You can't use `in` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

A function mathematically is defined by its unique map from input to output. A sequence is created by forwarding output to a new function. So the natural way to do sequences in Haskell is *function composition* `... f2 . f1`. Sometimes a function returns more than what is needed for the next step. So you need `let` or `where` to extract what you want to forward to the next step.

*forward* only refers to *from output to input*. From *input to output* it is a *map* between different variables (a *function*).

*Nothing is ever changed*. No side effect.

`do` notation is also function composition. You might think something (*Monad*) is handled through the functions and possibly changed, but it is *not changed*. Instead of a change a modified copy is constructed. Well, ideally, because `IO`-like Monads will do changes to the outside world.